# Problems with Mock Server when running Pact with Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, pact

I am trying to use **Pact** in my **Angular 13** workspace with **Jest** for writing contract tests.
I am using latest version of Pact which is **v10.4.1**.

However, I am running into problems related to Mock Server.
It seems that Mock Server is not receiving any requests.
I have added multiple debug logs to check which URL is used by Angular's HttpClient and it appears to point correctly to Mock Server's dynamic URL. See this -

```
console.log
**** Adding Interaction with path: /users/1
  at src/app/services/user.service.pact.spec.ts:44:15

console.log
**** MockServer:: URL: http://127.0.0.1:50118, ID: unknown
  at src/app/services/user.service.pact.spec.ts:65:17

console.log
**** UserService.get(): http://127.0.0.1:50118/users/1
  at UserService.get (src/app/services/user.service.ts:29:13)
```

From above -

- Mock Server is running at `http://127.0.0.1:50118`.
- Has one interaction registered with path as `/users/1`.
- And Client is making http request to `http://127.0.0.1:50118/users/1`.

But still it's not working.

Also, I am not sure why **Mock Server Id** is coming out as "**undefined**".

Error I get is as below -

```
RUNS  src/app/services/user.service.pact.spec.ts
2023-02-08T10:33:00.360413Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) pact_matching::metrics: Could not get the tokio runtime, will not send metrics - there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime
2023-02-08T10:33:00.360795Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) pact_mock_server::server_manager: Shutting down mock server with ID ca85dcf4-01b7-4d4e-af7a-890baaa75559 - MockServerMetrics { requests: 0 }
2023-02-08T10:33:00.363789Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) pact_mock_server::mock_server: Mock server ca85dcf4-01b7-4d4e-af7a-890baaa75559 shutdown - MockServerMetrics { request  console.error
    Unhandled Promise rejection: Test failed for the following reasons:

      Mock server failed with the following mismatches:

        0) The following request was expected but not received:
            Method: GET
            Path: /users/1 ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Test failed for the following reasons:

      Mock server failed with the following mismatches:

        0) The following request was expected but not received:
            Method: GET
            Path: /users/1
        at PactV3.<anonymous> (C:\angular-pact\node_modules\@pact-foundation\src\v3\pact.ts:227:29)
        at step (C:\angular-pact\node_modules\@pact-foundation\pact\src\v3\pact.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (C:\angular-pact\node_modules\@pact-foundation\pact\src\v3\pact.js:14:53)
        at fulfilled (C:\angular-pact\node_modules\@pact-foundation\pact\src\v3\pact.js:5:58)
        at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\angular-pact\node_modules\zone.js\bundles\zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:409:30)
```

May be I am missing something very trivial/basic, I would really appreciate if you have any clue / suggestion on what might be wrong in my project?

I have uploaded my Angular project to [GitHub here](https://github.com/subodhgodbole/angular-pact), where this is reproducible. (After cloning, command to run is `npm run test:pact`).

Comment: @matthew-fellows - Can I please bring in your attention to this issue? I would really appreciate if you can look into this soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. Your `executeTest` callback is completing before the request has been sent. (When the Promise from the callback you passed to `executeTest` resolves, Pact expects you to have sent the request). To fix this, you need to not resolve your callback until you have sent the request.
2. The use of `done` inside that test callback is not waiting for Pact to run its test (which means that the test will incorrectly pass if/when it is actually failing). To fix this, you must await or return the `provider.executeTest(...)` call.

I don't know angular, but changing your test from:

```
    it('should get a User', (done) => {
      provider.executeTest(async(mockServer) => {
        console.log(`**** MockServer:: URL: ${mockServer.url}, ID: ${mockServer.id}`);
        service.setUrlPrefix(mockServer.url);

        service.get(userId).subscribe({
          next: (response) => {
            console.debug(response);
            expect(response).toEqual(expectedUser);
            done();
          },
          error: (error: HttpErrorResponse)=> {
            done();
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

to:

```
    it('should get a User', () => {
      return provider.executeTest(async (mockServer) => {
        console.log(
          `**** MockServer:: URL: ${mockServer.url}, ID: ${mockServer.id}`
        );
        service.setUrlPrefix(mockServer.url);

        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
          service.get(userId).subscribe({
            next: (response) => {
              console.debug(response);
              expect(response).toEqual(expectedUser);
              resolve();
            },
            error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              reject(error);
            },
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

will at least fix it. Of course, there might be a more idiomatic way to wait for the request in Angular.